# Repetir grupo pai a cada interação do grupo filho

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, reporting-services

Estou com a seguinte situação. Eu possuo uma estrutura de dados que segue a seguinte hierarquia.

- 1 *Navio* possui N *empresas exportadoras*
- 1 *Empresa* exportadora possui N *notas de exportações*
- 1 *Nota de exportação* possui N *fornecedores de produto*
- 1 *Fornecedor de produto* possui N endereços de *origem de produto*

Com base nessa hierarquia estou tentando montar um relatório paginado com a seguinte regra,

- Cada paginação do relatório deve ser por endereço de origem do produto.

  - Todos grupos superiores devem se repetir nas outras páginas.

Eu tentei montar um relatório usando listas aninhadas, mas ele só funciona na primeira página. Nas outras partes ele não repete os grupos superiores.

A minha necessidade é sempre repetir os grupos superiores a cada paginação do grupo menor.

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Provavelmente é um erro no uso do tal "reporting services" (que não sei qual o o que é).

Comment: É o MS SQL Reporting Services. Ferramenta de produção e distribuição de relatórios da Microsoft